# jQuery event not firing on change event

Tags: jquery

I have a problem that I cannot seem to figure out.  I have a JavaScript file with jQuery that looks something like:

```
$(document).ready(function() 
{
    $("body").css('cursor', 'progress');

    ...

    $("#statusText").on('change', function() 
    {
        $("body").css('cursor', 'default');
    });
    ...
});
```

Generally, its function is to have the document display a progress cursor until the last element to have data loaded into it from an ajax call (statsText).  The event is handled by:

```
var reqStatus = response.status;
$("#statusText").text(reqStatus).trigger('change');
```

However, when I test this out in my browser, it does not do anything, my page still displays the waiting cursor.  I then manually trigger the change event using the console in IE, but it still doesn't do anything.  It isn't until I copy the `$("#statusText").on('change'...` into the console, run it, and then trigger the change event manually, will the cursor go back to normal.  I realize this probably isn't the best way to do this, and this is more of a PoC, but I am having trouble understanding why this event won't work.  I was actually able to implement this functionality earlier, and it was working, but I had to delete that copy, and it doesn't seem to want to work this time.

I'm guessing the problem is that the function is getting called properly in the `document.ready()` function, but I don't know why that is.

EDIT: Thanks to Minitech's comment, which he deleted, he instructed me to try Javascript.  After using Javascript to handle it, rather than JQuery, it worked as intended.  Is there a reason for this?

Comment: Put an alert in your `change` event handler and make sure you're getting there.

Comment: Are you replacing `#statusText` within your script (e.g. via content brought through an ajax call)?

Comment: @JaneS stupid me forgot to even test that way :P.  Still, I am not seeing any alert when I added it in there.

Comment: @user3334871 Try using `$('#statusText').change(function() { ... }` instead.

Comment: @NickTomlin As far as I'm aware, I am not (It's a 1,000 line JS file, will take me a bit to find if I am).  If I type in $("#statusText").text("Here I am"); it will display correctly in the page, so I assume it's name is the same throughout.  The id name is just for a span located in my HTML code

Comment: Oh and are you getting any errors in the console?

Comment: @JaneS still nothing :(  And I am not getting any errors in the console

Comment: Is your `$(document).ready()` function firing?  Have you placed an alert in there?  Also is `statusText` statically created on the page?

Comment: @JaneS It is firing, since I have about 1,000 other scripting event going on correctly.

Comment: Is reqStatus valid?  If it's not it may prevent it from bubbling up to the change event

Comment: But did you place an alert directly before your `change` event in the `(document).ready()` definiton (rather than at the top), just to make sure you aren't exiting before it reaches it?

Comment: @Kevin It is valid, but I am using the actual file loaded into my browser to test.  I am not relying on the response to fire it, but rather I am testing using a manual trigger through the console.  I actually changed it to Javascript to handle it, and it worked...still not sure why JQuery failed and JS succeeded.

Comment: try $('body').on('change', '#statusText', function(){ alert('test'); });